# Camera recording preview after a few seconds, the card screen and record failed it shows following error:

Tags: camera, recording

Camera recording preview after a few seconds, the card screen and record failed

```
        11-23 14:53:51.719 15121-27308/com.example.android.mediarecorder I/HWSERVICES: hwnative_get_component  comes...
        11-23 14:53:51.729 15121-27308/com.example.android.mediarecorder I/HwMediaPermWrapper: confirmCameraPermission, blocked:false
        11-23 14:53:51.734 15121-27308/com.example.android.mediarecorder I/MediaRecorder: start
        11-23 14:53:52.054 15121-27308/com.example.android.mediarecorder I/MediaRecorder: sendStateChangedIntent, state=3
        11-23 14:53:56.494 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder I/MediaRecorder: stop
        11-23 14:53:56.619 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/MediaRecorderEx: stop failed: -1007
        11-23 14:53:56.654 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 3 is not owned by the client (state=0)
        11-23 14:53:56.654 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 4 is not owned by the client (state=3)
        11-23 14:53:56.659 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 0 is not owned by the client (state=0)
        11-23 14:53:56.659 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 1 is not owned by the client (state=0)
        11-23 14:53:56.659 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 2 is not owned by the client (state=0)
        11-23 14:53:56.659 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 3 is not owned by the client (state=0)
        11-23 14:53:56.664 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 4 is not owned by the client (state=3)
        11-23 14:53:56.664 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 5 is not owned by the client (state=0)
        11-23 14:53:56.664 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 6 is not owned by the client (state=0)
        11-23 14:53:56.664 15121-15121/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-15121-0] cancelBuffer: slot 7 is not owned by the client (state=0)
```

who can help me to resolve above problem?